# What to do with large dimension tables

Tags: data-warehouse

I've a products dimension (garments). Every garment can have multiple colors and each color can have multiple sizes. The colors are created at source by designers so they can range from things like `pistachio` to `passion red`, same with the sizes - they can be normal number ranges but they can also be things like `Up to 6 months` or `5 Year old`.

The product variants when you take into account all the products their sizes and their colors come to approx 6 million records. On-top of that we have scd type2 on the dimension. The performance is not the best, so I have separated the products colors and sizes into three separate dimension (colors and sizes are almost like big-mini dimension)

Performance is much better now, but obviously I have to go and include the color and sizes keys in the fact table. I can still query between the three dimensions as I have the product key in both the color and size dimension.

My question is: Am I doing this right? Should I separate the products up in this way or should the colors and size be in the product at all cost? If so how should I tackle the large row count using this method?

Answer (score 0):

If your design is meeting the business needs and performance is no longer an issue then it sounds like what you've done is fine.

You will also be able to quickly and easily report by sizes / colors so that trends can be seen, and if a complete list of all products is need you can do this in a view in order to replicate the original list.